# Can't get python to read/display my variable

Tags: python, class, variables

I have been working on this one program for hours now and I am still having no luck. I am trying to create a "search engine" where you can look products with a SKU number.

```
class SKU:
    def __init__(self, name, product):
        self.name = name
        self.product = product 
    def displaySKU(self):
        print "Sku Number : ", self.name,  ", Product: ", self.product

sku90100 = SKU("90100", "10310, 00310")
sku90101 = SKU("90101", "10024, 00024")
sku90102 = SKU("90102", "10023")
sku90103 = SKU("90103", "10025")
sku90104 = SKU("90104", "10410")
search = input("Please type SKU Number")
if search in range(90100, 90106):
    "sku",search.displaySKU
```

My problem is that I can't seem to get display the SKU information; I have tried removing, changing, and adding characters to the variables without success. I may have missed something thou, but all I now is that nothing that I try works. Please help me figure this out, and thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: Do you know what the error is displaying as?

Comment: `search` would be a string with your user input, not an instance of `SKU` (since you defined `displaySKU` as a method of it).  Consider looking into [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) as it is a data structure that will help you with what you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of storing each product as its own variable, use a `dict`:

```
skus = {}
skus[90100] = SKU("90100", "10310, 00310")
skus[90101] = SKU("90101", "10024, 00024")
skus[90102] = SKU("90102", "10023")
skus[90103] = SKU("90103", "10025")
skus[90104] = SKU("90104", "10410")
```

Then you can check membership using `in`, and call the `.displaySKU()` method to print:

```
if search in skus:
    skus[search].displaySKU()
```

Lastly, for Python 2, it's preferred to use `raw_input` instead of `input`. `raw_input` gives you a string though, so you want to convert that to an `int` to match your skus keys:

```
search = int(raw_input("Please type SKU Number"))
```

Comment: OP's problem is not creating a SKU object to call the `displaySKU` method of. The rest of the program structure may be clunky, but fixing it doesn't answer the question.